# Image size java

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to design a character but I don't know how to input a image of a face where the stick figure head is at and how to size the image? What is the simplest way to code that in java?

```
 package com.udacity.gamedev.stickfigure;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;

    import java.awt.Color;

    public class StickFigure extends ApplicationAdapter {

    // Declare
    ShapeRenderer renderer;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // Initialize
        renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // Dispose
        renderer.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);

        // Head
        renderer.circle(100, 100, 20);
        renderer.end();

        renderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);

        // Torso
        renderer.line(100, 50, 100, 100);

        // Legs
        renderer.line(85, 35, 100, 50);
        renderer.line(115, 35, 100, 50);

        // Arms
        renderer.line(85, 70, 100, 85);
        renderer.line(115, 70, 100, 85);
        renderer.end();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yawak.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using GL, you could make a simple game entirely with Awt or Swing.  This is a tutorial that shows how with Awt: http://www.kilobolt.com/day-2-basic-framework

However, this would be for 2D games and not 3d.  Awt or Swing would be a little easier than using GL.  With GL I would imagine you would have to use a method to load an image and draw it to the location of the circle.  That's a little cumbersome when you could have the head drawn already and just load the complete head image.

Most 2D games use sprite sheets where the image is already completed and you load it from memory and draw it to the screen at a location.

Comment: Will a Awt or Swing work the same with a sprite sheet